# SpagoBI 5.2 doen‘t shows the saved datasets. What should I do?

Tags: database, oracle, tomcat, configuration, spagobi

I have an error in SpagoBI 5.2 in which I unfortunately could not find a solution on the Internet.
I use my own Tomcat version 8.0.37 in which I want to deploy the WebApps (All-in-Oneis not an alternative for me). I proceeded as follows:

1. declared environment variables.
2. created the schema on the Oracle database. (ORA-create.sql and-create-quartz-schema.sql)
3. deployed the WebApp "SpagoBI", so the folder is created with the necessary configuration files.
4. edited the **server.xml** to connect to Oracle. (added environment variables and the metadata source)
5. edited the **hibernate.cfg.xml** and **jbpm.hibernate.cfg.xml** to address the correct driver.
6. added more resources in the lib-folder

   - casclient.jar
   - commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
   - commons-logging-api-1.1.jar
   - concurrent.jar
   - foo-commonj.jar
   - geronimo-commonj_1.1_spec-1.0.jar
   - iijdbc.jar
   - ojdbc7.jar

SpagoBI I could reach without problems.
Now the problem: When I create a dataset that is saved successfully. but I want it to edit or delete, the dataset does **not** appear in the environment. But in the database it is available. Can somebody help me?

[saved Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d40t5.jpg)
[reloaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frt7x.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

There can be 2 cases.

**CASE 1:**

You try to save it twice and check whether the username & save time comes on bottom right corner window of the same screen whose image you have posted.

**CASE 2:**

You need to create 1 datasource where meta-data of SpagoBI is stored.
You should make it write-default true.
After that it will be visible.
But you need to re-install the spago as on the current set-up it wont work.